# Connect with database from NextJS api route in efficient way

Tags: mongodb, aws-lambda, next.js, google-cloud-functions, serverless

Consider, I have two API routes in Next.js, one is `/foo` and the other one is `/boo`. The main purpose of both routes is to retrieve data from a database, let's say MongoDB. I have a function named `connect()` that is responsible for connecting to the MongoDB. Now, my question is, do I have to call `connect()` inside both the `/foo` and `/boo` routes? I think yes, because both routes require retrieving data from the database. However, I am confused whether it is good practice to connect to the database inside a route. If a user refreshes or goes from `/foo` to `/boo`, it will connect to the database again, which is definitely not efficient.

Comment: cache and reuse the db connection? [something](https://github.com/cmgchess/facemash-v2/blob/master/serverless/lib/database.js) i had tried